# Sum of columns based on range of values of other columns in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym': ['a', 'b'], 'vol_1': [100, 50], 'price_1': [5, 150], 'vol_2': [1500, 2000], 'price_2': [20, 175],
                   'vol_3': [123, 500], 'price_3': [22, 1000], 'min': [18, 150], 'max': [23, 176]})
```

I want to add a column that sums `vol_1`, `vol_2`, and `vol_3` for each row if the price that is in the next column for each vol is in range of `min` and `max` cols.
For example for the first row I want `vol_2` and `vol_3` because the prices are in range of `min` and `max`.
My desired outcome looks like this:

```
 sym  vol_1  price_1  vol_2  price_2  vol_3  price_3  min  max  vol_sum
0   a    100        5   1500       20    123       22   18   23     1623
1   b     50      150   2000      175    500     1000  150  176     2050
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Reshape](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) the data so you have individual columns for `vol`, `price`, `min` and `max`. Next, [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for only rows where `price` is between `min` and `max`, group by the `sym` column and append result to `df`.

```
df["vol_sum"] = (pd.wide_to_long(df,
                                 stubnames=["vol", "price"], 
                                 i=["sym", "min", "max"], 
                                 j="number", 
                                 sep="_")
                  .query("min <= price <= max", engine="python")
                  .groupby("sym")
                  .vol
                  .sum()
                  .array
                 )



   sym  vol_1   price_1 vol_2   price_2 vol_3   price_3 min max vol_sum
0   a   100      5      1500    20      123     22      18  23  1623
1   b   50      150     2000    175     500    1000     150 176 2050
```

update (13, October 2021):

If you choose not to convert to long form, a list comprehension could help; not so sure about the speed though :

```py
vols = [col for col in df if col.startswith('vol')]

bools = {f"vol{col[-2:]}" : df[col].between(df['min'], df['max'])
         for col in df 
         if col.startswith('price')}

df.assign(vol_sum = df[vols].mul(bools).sum(1))

  sym  vol_1  price_1  vol_2  price_2  vol_3  price_3  min  max  vol_sum
0   a    100        5   1500       20    123       22   18   23     1623
1   b     50      150   2000      175    500     1000  150  176     2050
```

Another option, using MultiIndexes:

```py
#select only vol and price columns
temp = df.filter(like='_')
# create MultiIndex
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split('_', expand = True)
#get conditions where price is between min and max
cond1 = temp.price.le(df['max'], axis = 0)
cond2 = temp.price.ge(df['min'], axis = 0)

#assign new column based on cond1 and cond2:
df.assign(vol_sum = temp.vol.where(cond1 & cond2).sum(1))
  sym  vol_1  price_1  vol_2  price_2  vol_3  price_3  min  max  vol_sum
0   a    100        5   1500       20    123       22   18   23   1623.0
1   b     50      150   2000      175    500     1000  150  176   2050.0
```

This should be faster than `pd.wide_to_long`, as the data size increases, as the data rows size remains the same(unlike `pd.wide_to_long`, which increases the number of rows)